# System.Exception: Too many Email Invocations: 11 Error

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I'm getting this error.

[[image]][[image]]

```
public class TelephoneMysteryResultHandler
    {
    //
    public static void handleBeforeInsert(List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> TriggerNew) {
        Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> UpdateMSS = new List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c>();
        for(Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c mss : TriggerNew) {
            if(mss.Send_Schedule__c != false) {
                clientIds.add(mss.Client_Information_Detail__c);
                UpdateMSS.add(mss);
            }
        }
        
        if(!clientIds.isEmpty() && !UpdateMSS.isEmpty()) {
            populateStartEndDateEmail(UpdateMSS,clientIds);
        }
    }
    //
    public static void handleBeforeUpdate(List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> TriggerNew, Map<Id,Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> TriggerOld) {
        Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> UpdateMSS = new List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c>();
        for(Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c mss : TriggerNew) {
            if(mss.Send_Schedule__c != false && TriggerOld.get(mss.Id).Send_Schedule__c != true) {
                clientIds.add(mss.Client_Information_Detail__c);
                UpdateMSS.add(mss);
            }
        }
        
        if(!clientIds.isEmpty() && !UpdateMSS.isEmpty()) {
            populateStartEndDateEmail(UpdateMSS,clientIds);
        }
    }
    
    //
    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> listOfNewMSS) {
        
        for(Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c mssRecord : listOfNewMSS) {
            if(mssRecord.Send_Schedule__c != false) {
                //Get the name of Email Template that should be use based on the Date and Time Status of the Telephone Mystery Result
                String emailTemplateName = identifyEmailTemplateNameBasedOnDateTimeStatus(mssRecord.Date_Status__c);
                if(String.isNotBlank(emailTemplateName)) {
                    sendEmailToShopper(mssRecord,getShopperInquiryTemplate(emailTemplateName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //
    
    public static void handleAfterUpdate(List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> listOfNewMSS,Map<Id,Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> TriggerOld) {
        for(Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c mssRecord : listOfNewMSS) {
            if(mssRecord.Send_Schedule__c != false && TriggerOld.get(mssRecord.Id).Send_Schedule__c != true) {
                //Get the name of Email Template that should be use based on the Date and Time Status of the Telephone Mystery Result
                String emailTemplateName = identifyEmailTemplateNameBasedOnDateTimeStatus(mssRecord.Date_Status__c);
                System.debug('Email Template Name = ' + emailTemplateName);
                if(String.isNotBlank(emailTemplateName)) {
                    sendEmailToShopper(mssRecord,getShopperInquiryTemplate(emailTemplateName));
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    //
    public static void populateStartEndDateEmail(List<Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c> UpdateMSS,Set<Id> clientIds)
    {
        
        Integer timeZoneHrs;
        Integer timeZoneMin;
        String finStrTime;
        String FinendTime;
        Time subthours;
        Time subtendhours;
        
        Map<Id, Client_Information_Details__c> clientInfo = new Map<Id, Client_Information_Details__c>([SELECT Id, 
                                                                                                        tolabel(Time_Zone__c) 
                                                                                                        FROM Client_Information_Details__c 
                                                                                                        where Id IN: clientIds]);
        if(clientInfo.isEmpty()) return;
        
        for(Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c mss : UpdateMSS) {
            if(clientInfo.containsKey(mss.Client_Information_Detail__c) && clientInfo.get(mss.Client_Information_Detail__c).Time_Zone__c != null) {
                
                String timeZone = clientInfo.get(mss.Client_Information_Detail__c).Time_Zone__c.subStringAfter(' ');
                String t;
                
                if(TimeZone != null || TimeZone != '')
                {
                    t= TimeZone;
                    //t = Integer.valueof(TimeZone.trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    t = '0';
                }
                
                system.debug('invite : '+t);
                if(t!= null && t.contains(':'))
                {
                    t = t.replaceall(':30',' ');
                    timeZoneHrs = Integer.valueof(t.trim());
                    timeZoneHrs = timeZoneHrs * -1;
                    if(timeZoneHrs > 0)
                    {
                        system.debug('>0');
                        timeZoneMin = -30;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        system.debug('<0');
                        timeZoneMin = 30;
                    }
                    timeZoneMin = timeZoneMin * -1;
                    system.debug(t);
                    system.debug(timeZoneHrs);
                    system.debug(timeZoneMin);
                }
                else if(t!= null && !t.contains(':'))
                {
                    timeZoneHrs = Integer.valueof(t.trim());
                    timeZoneHrs = timeZoneHrs * -1;
                    timeZoneMin = 0;
                    system.debug(t);
                    system.debug(timeZoneHrs);
                }
                
                system.debug('invite after : '+timeZoneHrs);
                system.debug('invite after : '+timeZoneMin);
                
                System.debug('date of call' + mss.Date_of_Call__c);
                
                if(mss.Start_Time_Email_Template__c != null){
                    system.debug('timeZoneHrs: '+timeZoneHrs);
                    system.debug('timeZoneMin: '+timeZoneMin);
                    System.debug('Start Time ===' +mss.Start_Time_Email_Template__c);
                    subthours=mss.Start_Time_Email_Template__c.addHours(timeZoneHrs);
                    subthours=subthours.addMinutes(timeZoneMin);
                    String strTime=String.valueOf(subthours);
                    String repstrTime=strTime.remove(':');
                    finStrTime=repstrTime.removeEnd('.000Z');
                }
                else{
                    finStrTime='043000';
                }
                if(mss.End_Time_Email_Template__c != null)
                {
                    system.debug('timeZoneHrs: '+timeZoneHrs);
                    system.debug('timeZoneMin: '+timeZoneMin);
                    System.debug('End Time ===' +mss.End_Time_Email_Template__c);
                    subtendhours=mss.End_Time_Email_Template__c.addHours(timeZoneHrs);
                    subtendhours=subtendhours.addMinutes(timeZoneMin);
                    String enTime=String.valueOf(subtendhours);
                    String replendTime=enTime.remove(':');
                    FinendTime=replendTime.removeEnd('.000Z');
                }
                else{
                    FinendTime='083000';
                }
                system.debug('finstrTime'+FinStrTime);
                system.debug('finendTime'+FinendTime);
                Integer strYear=mss.Date_of_Call__c.year();
                Integer strMonth=mss.Date_of_Call__c.month();
                Integer strDay=mss.Date_of_Call__c.day();
                String month;
                String day;
                if(strMonth < 9)
                {
                    month='0'+string.valueOf(strMonth);
                }
                else
                {
                    month=string.valueOf(strMonth);
                }
                if(strDay < 9)
                {
                    day='0'+string.valueOf(strDay);
                }
                else
                {
                    day=string.valueOf(strDay);
                }
                string startdatetime;
                String checksTime = FinStrTime.substring(0,2);
                String checkTime = FinendTime.substring(0,2);
                if((checkTime == '00' || checkTime == '01' || checkTime == '02' || checkTime == '03' || checkTime == '04' || checkTime == '05' || checkTime == '06' || checkTime == '07' || checkTime == '08' || checkTime == '09' || checkTime == '10' || checkTime == '11')
                   &&
                   (checksTime != '00' || checksTime != '01' || checksTime != '02' || checksTime != '03' || checksTime != '04' || checksTime != '05' || checksTime != '06' || checksTime != '07' || checksTime != '08' || checksTime != '09' || checksTime != '10' || checksTime != '11'))
                {
                    strDay = strDay+1;
                    day=string.valueOf(strDay);
                    
                    
                    startdatetime=String.valueOf(strYear)+month+day+'T'+FinStrTime+'Z';
                    mss.Start_Date_Email__c = startdatetime;
                    System.debug('start date'+startdatetime);
                    
                }
                else {
                    startdatetime=String.valueOf(strYear)+month+day+'T'+FinStrTime+'Z';
                    mss.Start_Date_Email__c = startdatetime;
                    System.debug('start date'+startdatetime);
                }
                String enddatetime;
                
                
                enddatetime= String.valueOf(strYear)+month+day+'T'+FinendTime+'Z';
                mss.End_Date_Email__c = enddatetime;
                System.debug('end date'+enddatetime);
            }
        }
    }
    //
    private static string identifyEmailTemplateNameBasedOnDateTimeStatus(String dateTimeStatus) {
        String emailTemplateName = ''; 
        //If Date and Time Status equals to Flexible, Flexible Date Only, and Flexible Time Only
        
        if(dateTimeStatus == 'Flexible' || dateTimeStatus == 'Flexible Date Only' || dateTimeStatus == 'Flexible Time Only') {
            emailTemplateName = 'Shopper_Inquiry_Assignment';
        }
        else {
            emailTemplateName = 'Shopper_Inquiry_Assignment_No_Flexibility';
        }
        return emailTemplateName;
    }
    //
    private static Id getShopperInquiryTemplate(String emailTemplateName) {
        return [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = :emailTemplateName LIMIT 1].Id;
    }
    
    //method to send mail to a list of users
    private static void sendEmailToShopper(Mystery_Shopping_Schedule__c mssRecord, Id shopperInquiryEmailTemplateId) {
        
        Datetime dtimeOfShopper;
        Date dateOfShoper;
        String shopperDate;
        Date dtOfCall; 
        String dateOfCall;
        Date altDate;
        String altDateOfCall;
        
        if(mssRecord.Shopper_Date_of_Call__c != null) {
            dtimeOfShopper = mssRecord.Shopper_Date_of_Call__c;
            dateOfShoper = dtimeOfShopper.date();
            shopperDate = dateOfShoper.format();
        }
        
        if(mssRecord.Date_of_Call__c != null) {
            dtOfCall = mssRecord.Date_of_Call__c;
            dateOfCall = dtOfCall.format();
        }
        
        if(mssRecord.Alternate_Date_of_Call__c != null) {
            altDate = mssRecord.Alternate_Date_of_Call__c;
            altDateOfCall = altDate.format();
        }
        
        if(shopperInquiryEmailTemplateId == null) return;
        
        // Pick a dummy Contact
        Contact c = [SELECT id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1];
        
        // Send Email to Shopper
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String txtInvite = '';
        email.setToAddresses(new List<String> {mssRecord.Shopper_Email__c});    
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();   
        attach.filename = 'Appointment.ics'; 
        attach.ContentType ='text/calendar';
        attach.inline = true;     
        
        String allStrings = mssRecord.Type_of_Call__c + ' Mystery Shop Assignment for '+ mssRecord.Account_Name__c+'\n';
        txtInvite += 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n';        
        txtInvite += 'PRODID::-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN\n';
        txtInvite += 'VERSION:2.0\n';
        txtInvite += 'METHOD:PUBLISH\n';
        txtInvite += 'X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\n';
        txtInvite += 'BEGIN:VEVENT\n';
        txtInvite += 'CLASS:PUBLIC\n';
        txtInvite += 'ORGANIZER;CN='+mssRecord.createdby.Name+':MAILTO:'+mssRecord.createdby.Email+'\n';
        txtInvite += 'CREATED:20091026T203709Z\n';        
        txtInvite += 'DTEND:'+mssRecord.End_Date_Email__c+'\n';
        txtInvite += 'DTSTAMP:20191026T203709Z\n';        
        txtInvite += 'DTSTART:'+mssRecord.Start_Date_Email__c+'\n';
        txtInvite += 'LAST-MODIFIED:20091026T203709Z\n';
        txtInvite += 'LOCATION:'+mssRecord.Client_City__c+'\n';
        txtInvite += 'PRIORITY:5\n';
        txtInvite += 'SEQUENCE:0\n';
        txtInvite += 'SUMMARY;';
        txtInvite += 'LANGUAGE=en-us:Oculus ' +allStrings + '\n';
        txtInvite += 'DESCRIPTION:Hello, '+ mssRecord.Shopper_Name__c +'! Here is your '+ shopperDate +' Oculus Assignment' ;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nSTEP ONE ';
        txtInvite += '\\nReview the client information and requirements ' + mssRecord.Account_Name__c + ' located in ' + mssRecord.Client_City__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Client_Province__c + ', '+ mssRecord.Client_Country__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nSTEP TWO';
        txtInvite += '\\nThe call type is '+ mssRecord.Type_of_Call__c + '.';
        txtInvite += '\\n'+mssRecord.Call_Type_Explanation__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nWill you make a reservation? ' + mssRecord.Confirm__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nDetails in your local time zone.';
        txtInvite += '\\nYou must complete the call starting at ' + shopperDate;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nIMPORTANT:\\nYou have a two hour window to complete this call.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nClient Time Zone and Alternative Time Option';
        txtInvite += '\\nYou must complete the call on ' + dateOfCall + ' between ' + mssRecord.Time_Of_Calls__c +', '+ mssRecord.Time_Zone__c + ' Time Zone.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nIf you missed the call, it can be completed at ' + altDateOfCall + ' between ' + mssRecord.Alternate_Time_of_Calls__c + ', in the client\'s time zone, which is ' + mssRecord.Time_Zone__c + ' Time Zone.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nSTEP THREE \\nReview the Alias & Scenario Details. You are REQUIRED to use the Alias and Scenario details below. Please Review Carefully.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nALIAS INFORMATION';
        txtInvite += '\\n' + mssRecord.Alias_Name_fr__c + '\\nPersonality: ' + mssRecord.Suggested_Caller_Style__c + '\\nAlias Company: ' + mssRecord.AskedCompanyName__c + '\\nAlias Phone: ' + mssRecord.Alias_Telephone_Number_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '\\nAlias Address: ' + mssRecord.Alias_Address_fr__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Alias_City_fr__c +', ' + mssRecord.Alias_Province_State_fr__c+', '+ mssRecord.Alias_Postal_Code_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\n' + mssRecord.Alias_Email_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nAlias Credit Card Details\\n' + mssRecord.Alias_Card_Type__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nNumber: '+ mssRecord.Alias_Credit_Card_Number_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nExpiry: ' + mssRecord.Alias_Credit_Card_Expiry_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nDates to Check\\n'+ mssRecord.Dates_to_Check__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nOpening Statement\\n' + mssRecord.Suggested_Opening__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nScenario:\\n' + mssRecord.Scenario__c + ' ' + mssRecord.Specific_Call__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nClosing Statement:\\n' + mssRecord.Call_Closing__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nAdditional Information\\n' + mssRecord.Internal_Info__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nSTEP FOUR\\nCall Recording Requirements\\n\\nYou are required to record this conversation.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nKeep coughing and talking to a minimum.\\n\\nCall \\nenter access code';
        txtInvite += '\\n'+ mssRecord.Mystery_Call_Pin__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nThe system will dial the location automatically.\\nExtension, if listed:';
        txtInvite += '\\n' + mssRecord.Shop_Call_Extension__c;
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nPlease send any questions regarding your calls to our office. We are here to help.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\n\\nCall Notes, Terms & Conditions.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\n1. Each call should be attempted 3 times.';
        txtInvite += '\\nAfter three separate attempts, please inform the office that you were not able to get through with the 3 times you attempted. (They should be at least 15 minutes apart)';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\nIf you have been placed on hold for more than four minutes, your call is complete.\\nPlease hang up and inform your manager.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\n2. If the system is not accepting the number, call the office immediately.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\n3. Do not reschedule your call. The times are sensitive. Please contact the office or use the listed alternative time.';
        txtInvite += '\\n\\n4. If conducting a confirmation call, once you have a confirmation number, please ensure you forward the number to  or your manager.';
        
        
        txtInvite += 'TRANSP:OPAQUE\n';
        
        txtInvite += 'X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN"><HTML><HEAD><META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 08.00.0681.000"><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Hello, '+mssRecord.Shopper_Name__c + '! Here is your ' + shopperDate + ' TEST';
        txtInvite += '<br><b>STEP ONE</b>';
        txtInvite += '<br>Review the client information and requirements ' + mssRecord.Account_Name__c + ' located in ' + mssRecord.Client_City__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Client_Province__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Client_Country__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><b>STEP TWO</b>';
        txtInvite += '<br>The call type is ' + mssRecord.Type_of_Call__c + '.<br> ' + mssRecord.Call_Type_Explanation__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Will you make a reservation? ' + mssRecord.Confirm__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Details in your local time zone. <br>You must complete the call starting at ' + shopperDate;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>IMPORTANT: <br>You have a two hour window to complete this call.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Client Time Zone and Alternative Time Option <br>You must complete the call on ' + dateOfCall + ' between ' + mssRecord.Time_Of_Calls__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Time_Zone__c + ' Time Zone.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br><br>If you missed the call, it can be completed at ' + altDateOfCall + ' between ' + mssRecord.Alternate_Time_of_Calls__c + ', in the client\'s time zone, which is' + mssRecord.Time_Zone__c + ' Time Zone.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br><b>STEP THREE</b>';
        txtInvite += '<br>Review the Alias & Scenario Details. You are REQUIRED to use the Alias and Scenario details below. Please Review Carefully.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>ALIAS INFORMATION';
        txtInvite += '<br>'+mssRecord.Alias_Name_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '<br>Personality: '+ mssRecord.Suggested_Caller_Style__c;
        txtInvite += '<br>Alias Company: '+ mssRecord.AskedCompanyName__c;
        txtInvite += '<br>Alias Phone: '+ mssRecord.Alias_Telephone_Number_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '<br>Alias Address: '+ mssRecord.Alias_Address_fr__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Alias_City_fr__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Alias_Province_State_fr__c + ', ' + mssRecord.Alias_Postal_Code_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>' + mssRecord.Alias_Email_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Alias Credit Card Details';
        txtInvite += '<br>'+ mssRecord.Alias_Card_Type__c + 'Number: '+ mssRecord.Alias_Credit_Card_Number_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '<br>Expiry: ' + mssRecord.Alias_Credit_Card_Expiry_fr__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Dates to Check';
        txtInvite += '<br>' + mssRecord.Dates_to_Check__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Opening Statement';
        txtInvite += '<br>' + mssRecord.Suggested_Opening__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Scenario:';
        txtInvite += '<br>' + mssRecord.Scenario__c;
        txtInvite += '<br>' + mssRecord.Specific_Call__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Closing Statement:';
        txtInvite += '<br>' + mssRecord.Call_Closing__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Additional Information';
        txtInvite += '<br>' + mssRecord.Internal_Info__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br><b>STEP FOUR</b>';
        txtInvite += '<br><b>Call Recording Requirements</b>';
        txtInvite += '<br>You are required to record this conversation.';
        txtInvite += '<br>Keep coughing and talking to a minimum.';
        txtInvite += '<br>enter access code';
        txtInvite += '<br>'+mssRecord.Mystery_Call_Pin__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br><br>The system will dial the location automatically.';
        txtInvite += '<br>Extension, if listed:';
        txtInvite += '<br>' + mssRecord.Shop_Call_Extension__c;
        txtInvite += '<br><br>People Care Support ● <a href=""></a>';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>Please send any questions regarding your calls to our office. We are here to help.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br><br>Call Notes, Terms & Conditions.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>1. Each call should be attempted 3 times.';
        txtInvite += '<br>After three separate attempts, please inform the office that you were not able to get through with the 3 times you attempted. (They should be at least 15 minutes apart)';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>If you have been placed on hold for more than four minutes, your call is complete.';
        txtInvite += '<br>Please hang up and inform your manager.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>2. If the system is not accepting the number, call the office immediately.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>3. Do not reschedule your call. The times are sensitive. Please contact the office or use the listed alternative time.';
        txtInvite += '<br><br>System ID: MCS-57526';
        txtInvite += '<br>'+' '+'</BODY></HTML>\n';
        
        txtInvite += 'X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY\n';
        txtInvite += 'X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\n';
        //set reminder
        txtInvite += 'BEGIN:VALARM\n';
        txtInvite += 'ACTION:Display\n';
        txtInvite += 'DESCRIPTION:Oculus '+allStrings;
        txtInvite += 'SUMMARY:Event Alarm\n';
        txtInvite += 'TRIGGER:-PT15M\n';
        txtInvite += 'END:VALARM\n';
        txtInvite += 'END:VEVENT\n';
        txtInvite += 'END:VCALENDAR';
        
        attach.body = Blob.valueOf(txtInvite);
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {attach});   
        email.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);  
        email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
        email.setWhatId(mssRecord.Id);
        email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
        email.setTemplateId(shopperInquiryEmailTemplateId);
        try{
            Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email> {email});
        }
        catch(EmailException ee) {
            System.debug('EMail Exceptipn = ' + ee.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never call methods which consume governors inside a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling

```
    Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email> {email});
```

in a loop, via `sendEmailToShopper()`, in both `handleAfterUpdate()` and `handleAfterInsert()`. As the error message tells you, you can only invoke an email send 10 times in a transaction. *Note* that doesn't mean 10 emails - it means 10 sends.

You're going to have to bulkify your code in much the same way that you do for DML and SOQL. Making `sendEmailToShopper()` return an email object that you can add to a list and send in a batch would be a good start on this project.

Comment: That what I was missing.
Thank you so much David